# Delete items from tableview row and core data simultaneously

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to delete items from a TableView and an entity called "Books." I have no idea if I'm remotely on the right track, however. When I try this code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var appdel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appdel.managedObjectContext!
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Books")

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

            addBook.myBooks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            context.deleteObject(addBook.myBooks[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject)

        }
    }
```

I get a warning on the last line that says "Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'NSManagedObject' always fails." Does anyone know how I can get around this? I've read that you can use a fetchedResultsController to handle core data in tables easily but I am new to programming and found that method a bit more confusing when setting up core data in general. Is the fetchedResultsController necessary to manage the data in my TableView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error it sounds like `addBook.myBooks` is an array of strings.

The immediate problem is that `deleteObject` doesn't work on strings, it works on managed objects-- that is, instances of `NSManagedObject` or a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. You can't delete a string from Core Data like that, you have to delete the managed object that corresponds to the string. The error is specifically telling you that `as! NSManagedObject` doesn't work on a string, because a string is a completely different kind of thing from a managed object.

[It's also a problem that you're removing the string at `indexPath.row` via `removeAtIndex`, and then later trying to use the string at `indexPath.row` that you just removed, but that's not the real problem here.]

What you need to do is find out the managed object that corresponds to the table view row you're deleting, and pass that to `deleteObject`. Without a fuller picture of how your view controller works it's impossible to say exactly how you would do that, but there are a couple of things that are clear:

1. Those first three lines in your method are not doing anything useful. Cut them-- even if you made them work, they'd be the wrong approach here. You don't want to have to **fetch** the managed object you're deleting right here. By the time you reach this method you should already know enough to delete it.
2. It's not **necessary** to use `NSFetchedResultsController` to put Core Data together with table views. But if you're new to programming you'll probably find things a lot easier if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save your context after deleteObject

```
context.deleteObject(addBook.myBooks![indexPath.row])
            addBook.myBooks.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            do {
                try context.save()
            }
            catch {
                print("Error")
            }

            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)


        }
```